# Error in printing 8byte integer in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, struct

I'm trying to assign a byte stream to a structure.The stream goes in the structure correctly as I can watch it in debugging window,but when I'm trying to print it the structure not showing 8byte integer value correctly.

Output:

```
serial no :: 1
Timestamp :: -1541974141
userid :: 0
```

Code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#pragma pack(push,1)
struct info
{
    int serialno;
    long long timestamp;
    int userid;
};
#pragma (pop)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    unsigned char arr[16];
    arr[0] = 0x01;
    arr[1] = 0x00;
    arr[2] =  0x00;
    arr[3] =  0x00;
    arr[4] = 0x83;
    arr[5] = 0x57;
    arr[6] = 0x17;
    arr[7] = 0xA4;
    arr[8] = 0xF6;
    arr[9] = 0x00;
    arr[10] = 0x00;
    arr[11] = 0x00;
    arr[12] = 0x00;
    arr[13] =  0x00;
    arr[14] =  0x00;
    arr[15] =  0x00;

    info *var;
    var = (info*)&arr[0];
    printf("serial no :: %d\n",var->serialno);
    printf("Timestamp :: %d\n",var->timestamp);
    printf("userid :: %d\n",var->userid);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: wrong format string! It should be: `printf("Timestamp :: %lld\n",var->timestamp);`. I'm pretty sure that compiler complains about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why `printf()` and friends are discouraged. They're not type safe. `%d` prints an `int`. You're passing a `long long`, so the internals of `printf()` truncate it into the `int` part.

Use `std::cout` instead, which will use the appropriately-sized overload:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "serial no :: " << var->serialno << '\n';
std::cout << "Timestamp :: " << var->timestamp << '\n';
std::cout << "userid :: " << var->userid << '\n';
```

Comment: so i think its not possible to use printf now i am using qdebug. The code is working fine

Comment: If you *really really* insist on using an unsafe C-style function (`printf()`) instead of the idiomatic C++ way (`std::cout`), you can use `%lld` as the format specifier. See [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). Note that `qdebug` works in debug builds only.

Answer (score 0):

Read [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) It is because of the architecture of the system you are seeing such behavior

In big-endian the integer value is stored in memory from lower to higher addresses . On a little-endian system it is vice-versa.

Comment: i am expert in endianess things, currently i am using a little-endian system and the byte stream is also in little-endian, the problem is related to printf printing format when i am using qdebug instead of printf its working fine

Comment: Please write "%lu"  or "%zu" whichever is applicable according, in place of "%d"